# Google Play Services - API version 6 is too high

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I'm developing an Android game using Unity3d 5.6.0f3. I have Google Play Services working fine on my Galaxy S6 Edge (Android 7.0). I integrated Google Play Services using the [CloudOnce](https://github.com/jizc/CloudOnce/blob/master/current-build/CloudOnce-v2.3.8.unitypackage) plugin.

Today I bought a Galaxy Tab A 8.0 (Android 6.0.1), and it can't connect to Google Play Services in my game. `logcat` yields the following errors:

```
07-20 14:49:46.616  7622  7962 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 11020000, Services 11055430, and Games 37240032
07-20 14:49:46.616  7622  7962 W GamesServiceBroker: Rejecting connection - api version 6 is too high
07-20 14:49:46.616 19423 19423 V GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
07-20 14:49:46.616 19423 19626 I GamesNativeSDK: UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
```

I downloaded Color Switch on the tablet and it was able to connect to Google Play Games, so it's an issue with my app or its configuration.

I'm not sure if "api version 6" refers to my device being on Android 6.0.1 or if that's just a coincidence. Has anybody else encountered this?

I'm happy to provide any other relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out this particular error message. Updating the `Google Play Games` app fixed it.

I checked Play Store for updates and it said there were none, but opening the store page for Google Play Games revealed an update.

I get the login prompt now, and it proceeds most of the way before failing with a "Unable to retrieve application ############ from network" error message.

I'm going to closing this question, as this new error is different and I can see other people have already solved this.

Comment: My new error ended up being caused by a misconfiguration of testers in the Google Play console. I had added the email address to the closed alpha testers list for the application, but not for Game Services (which hadn't been published yet).